# How to enable spell check for certain file types?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, spell-checking

I flip between Ruby and Markdown files a lot. Is there a way that I can have `set spell` automatically set when I open a `*.md` file, but not when I open a `*.rb` one?

Comment: I found this, but I don't think it works the way I want... https://ajayfromiiit.wordpress.com/2006/06/02/vim-applying-separate-settings-for-different-file-types-for-experienced-users-of-vim/

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/vim-spell-checking

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best way to set an option for a particular filetype is to use autocommands.

Here you could add something like that in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal spell
```

This line will trigger the command `setlocal spell` when the filetype of a buffer is set as markdown. you can also use the autocommand based on the extension of the file you edit with something like:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md setlocal spell
```

For more information you should read [`:h :autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:autocmd) and [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events).

---

**EDIT** Using autocommands is not the best way to do that.

First, if you use the autocommands remember to put them in an `augroup`:

```
augroup markdownSpell
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType markdown setlocal spell
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md setlocal spell
augroup END
```

This way if you source your vimrc several times the autocommands won't stack and get executed several times.

Now a better solution would be to use a ftplugin. To do that you want to create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.

This file will be sourced when the filetype of a buffer is set to `markdown` and after the `ftplugin` which comes with Vim by default has been sourced (this way you don't loose the already existing settings).

In this file you can simply add:

```
setlocal spell
```

Here you need to use `setlocal` instead of `set` to make sure that the settings will only apply to the current buffer and not to all buffers.

Some interesting related help topics:

- [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)
- [`:h :setlocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3asetlocal)

Comment: Great, thanks! This worked for me: `autocmd FileType latex,tex,md,markdown setlocal spell`

Comment: I'm glad it was useful to you :-)